# How to retrieve all rows thats co-ords are within a specifc radius in MySql Database

Tags: mysql, database, select

i am looking for a select statement that when given a specific set of co-ords(lng1+lat1) it will return all the rows within a 1km radius of lng1+lat1? this is to work with a mysql server?

```
      |_id_|_lat_|lng_|
row 1 | 1  | 1.3 |5.3 |
row 2 | 2  | 1.3 |5.2 |
row 3 | 3  | 2.3 |5.9 |
```

Comment: I suggest you look at spatial extensions rather than essentially rolling your own: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/spatial-extensions.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select * from table where POW((_lat_-lat1),2) + POW((_lng_-lng1),2) < 1
```

Comment: replace 1 with 0.5 . Pow returns a float anyway

Comment: ....when i try this `select * from table where POW((lat-53.282404),2) + POW((lng-(-6.388893)),2) < 1` i get everything in my database even though the radius is about 17km as i replace with .1 , .01,.001 the result set gets lower which means one of these is for a km radius , what one is it?

Comment: you should ask the guy who designed the table, it cant be 0.1 as if it was you wouldnt have got 17km. Try more test cases for deciding whether its 0.91 or 0.001. Also consider the fact that it could be in 100s or 1000s of miles,